# Time series forecasting: classical methods vs. machine learning / artificial intelligence

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, references, artificial-intelligence

Do you know papers that researched how accurate predictions are using time series or AI? I see more papers using VAR/VECM than XGBoost. Do you guys know why this?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question, because the applications vary a lot. There are short series and there are long series. There are series with strong signal and weak noise and there are the opposite. Machine learning methods are likely to do well with long series and strong signal. Classical time series methods may do better with short series and weak signal. (But that applies more generally than just to time series.)

Makridakis ["Interview about M4, Foresight"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322331876_Interview_about_M4_Foresight) (2018) talks about this. He says machine learning methods underperform classical time series models, but the machine learning community does not accept this:

> Our conclusions were quite straightforward: the forecasting accuracy of all ML methods was inferior to that of statistical ones. Not only that, but the accuracy of the Naïve 2 benchmark was better than half the ML methods. We were excited by the results, and sent the paper to the journal Neural Networks. We got back a letter from them saying that other studies have
> proven the superiority of ML methods, so our results could not be right. The paper was rejected without even a peer review!

> We then wrote at least 10 letters to the editor asking about the studies purporting to show the superiority of ML. Against all academic tradition, we received no response. Nothing. And our own search of statistical data bases, including Google Scholar and Scopus, found no studies proving the superiority of ML methods.

See also Makridakis et al. ["Statistical and Machine Learning forecasting methods: Concerns and ways forward"](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0194889) (2018). It says that traditional statistical time series models consistently dominate the machine learning methods in forecasting monthly data. (However, the authors might not be entirely fair to the ML methods. To keep computational costs manageable, the latter are not tuned all that thoroughly. In practice it should be possible to tune them more, given sufficient computational resources.)

However, that was 2018. In the M5 competition (2020), a machine learning method won. It was [a method](https://www.kaggle.com/c/m5-forecasting-accuracy/discussion/163684) that in a sense aggregated classical time series models/forecasts. (Though it may not be obvious from the description linked above, it was discussed as such rather clearly in a [Forecasting Impact](https://forecasters.org/publications/forecasting-impact-podcast/) podcast; cannot remember which episode, though; perhaps the one with Rob Hyndman.) It was based on them, yet it was able to improve over them just a bit, and that was sufficient to win the competition.

If the M competitions are any guide, it seems machine learning has caught up just recently with the classical time series methods. Even if they actually employ the classical time series methods under the hood, machine learning methods are now able to beat them in some instances.

Comment: +1, but note that in the 2018 interview, Makridakis was talking about the much earlier M3 competition in 2000, in the context of the run-up to the M4 competition, which was also won by Slawek Smyl's ML method.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, thank you. I had forgotten that. My impression is that Makridakis was overall skeptical regarding ML methods for time series forecasting all the way to 2018. Regarding *our own search of statistical data bases, including Google Scholar and Scopus, found no studies proving the superiority of ML methods*, I suppose that includes studies newer than 2000, though I cannot guarantee that. It has been a while since I read Makridakis' papers.

Comment: I think your impression re the skepticism of Makridakis about ML until 2018 is spot on. That used to be more general among the forecasting crowd I am involved with. It has changed very much in the last few years.